# How do I correctly find a string in a 2D char array?

Tags: c++

The following code wants the user to input 3 words which will then be searched in the char array mrx.txt(found below for reference).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    const int anz=20;
    char mrx [anz][anz];        // memory for char array
    for (int i=0; i<anz; i++)
        for (int j=0; j<anz; j++)
            mrx[i][j] = '?';    // assign start value

    ifstream in ("mrx.txt");    // read file
    if (!in)                    // only continue program if file exists
    {
        cout << "File mrx.txt could not be opened!" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    for (int i=0; i<anz; i++)
        for (int j=0; j<anz; j++)
            in >> mrx[i][j];    // initialize letters and save them

    in.close();

    char word[3][anz+1];        // memory for user input
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter word " << i+1 << " now: ";
        cin >> word[i];
    }
    cout << endl << endl;
    
    //problematic code in question

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
      for(int a = 0; a < anz; a++){
        string str = mrx[a];
        string str2 = word[i];
        size_t found = str.find(str2);
        if (found!=string::npos){
          std::cout << word[i] << " | [" << a + 1 << "] [" << found + 1 << "] | rechts\n";
        }
      }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

mrx.txt:

```
i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i
i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i
i i i p u m a i i i i i i i i i i i i i
i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i
i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i
i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i
i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i
i i i i i i i i i i i i i i f i i i i i
i i i i i i i i i i i i i i u i i i i i
i i i i i i i i i i i i i i c i i i i i
i i i i i i i i i i i i i i h i i i i i
d r a p o e l i i i i i i i s i i i i i
i i i u i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i
i i i m i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i
i i i a i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i
i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i s
i i i i i i i i i i p u m a i i i i i h
i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i c
i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i u
i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i l
```

When starting the code I get following output in the console:

```
puma | [1] [44] | rechts
puma | [2] [24] | rechts
puma | [3] [4] | rechts
puma | [4] [271] | rechts
puma | [5] [251] | rechts
puma | [6] [231] | rechts
puma | [7] [211] | rechts
puma | [8] [191] | rechts
puma | [9] [171] | rechts
puma | [10] [151] | rechts
puma | [11] [131] | rechts
puma | [12] [111] | rechts
puma | [13] [91] | rechts
puma | [14] [71] | rechts
puma | [15] [51] | rechts
puma | [16] [31] | rechts
puma | [17] [11] | rechts
```

It shows too many lines that are not wanted. What I want the output to look like is this:

```
puma | [3] [4] | rechts
puma | [17] [11] | rechts
```

The problem most definitely lies in the lower bracket of the code marked by the comment `//problematic code in question`.
What am I doing wrong/how do I adjust my code for the wanted output?

Comment: So, did you try to debug your program?

Comment: @Quimby What exactly do you mean with debug? I am fairly new to programming.

Comment: You managed to search to find a place to ask this question, so you should also be able to search for what debugging means ;-)

Comment: @Sidon I mean running a debugger. Not sure if/which IDE you use, but you should learn how to step through the execution of your program line by line and inspect all local variables.

Comment: Funny: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65608473/how-do-i-find-a-word-in-this-2d-array#comment116001150_65608473

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string str = mrx[a];
```

`mrx` is a `char [][]`, so `mrx[a]` is a `char []`. This decays to a `char *`, and this statement uses `std::string`'s assignment operator overload that initializes the `std::string` from a `char *`.

As you know, this `char *` is interpreted as a C-style string ***that's terminated by a null byte***. Your 2D matrix has no such thing. No `\0` bytes anywhere. This results in undefined behavior. Your false positives are an artifact of the memory layout of the 2D `char` array.

To fix this, either rearrange the matrix to add an additional `'\0'` character at the end of the row, which you are responsible for correctly initializing, or construct each `std::string` using the overloaded constructor that takes a beginning and an ending iterator, that you set to the beginning and one-past-the-end of each row.